# Issue Dynamically Changing HighCharts Chart Title

Tags: highcharts

I am having an issuing changing the title dynamically in a chart.  I am following the workaround [here](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/39C3U/3/) to change the chart title in such a way that the change is reflected when exporting the chart.  This workaround is referenced in the bug report [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/48).  However, when you click the "Set Title" twice in the workaround example the chart tile loses its formatting.  Is there any way to work around this?

```
chart.setTitle( { text: 'Head Count Terminations' }, { text: 'Sales' } );
chart.options.title = {
    text: 'Head Count Terminations'
};
chart.options.subtitle = {
    text: 'Sales'
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It probably loses its formatting because the entire title object is replaced. What about only setting the text property?

```
chart.setTitle( { text: 'Head Count Terminations' }, { text: 'Sales' } );
chart.options.title.text = 'Head Count Terminations';
chart.options.subtitle.text = 'Sales';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid that issue, by overwriting exportin buttons and options for export.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/HvHVU/

Function:

```
function exportActualChart() {
    this.exportChart({}, {
        title: {
            text: this.title.text
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: this.subtitle.text
        }
    });
}
```

Chart options

```
    exporting: {
        buttons: {
            exportButton: {
                menuItems: [{
                    text: 'Standard export',
                    onclick: function () {
                        this.exportChart();
                    }
                }, {
                    text: 'With new title',
                    onclick: exportActualChart
                },
                null,
                null]
            }
        }
    }
```